# Using Class vectors to display the contents. Vector.size() goes to 0 when not in constructor

Tags: c++, class, vector

So I am trying to make a program that stores polynomials the user enters as vectors, then my program will allow to the user to do operations on these polynomials with overloaded operators. However, when I create a class object, using my constructor the proper vector is created, but when I try and use the same vector in (for example) a function, its size is set to 0. I've done the old fashion of just cout ing some number at different points in the program to identify the error.

NOTE: I am using namespace std

Here is the header file with only the items related to this question:

```
Class Polynom{
public:
...
Polynom(const vector<int>& coeff);
...
ostream& insert(ostream& sout);
...
private:
...
vector<int> P;
};
```

Here is the implementation file

```
Polynom::Polynom(const vector<int>& coeff)
{
   vector<int> P(coeff) //coping the vector provided into a class vector
   cout << "A polynomia was created with the desired coefficient values" << endl;
   //Here is a for loop i made to ensure that P = coeff
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i<P.size(); i++)
   {
   cout << P[i] << " ";
   }
   cout << "Those were the content of P" << endl;
}
ostream& Polynom::insert(ostream& sout)
{
   ...
   unsigned int exponent;
   exponent = P.size()-1; //Since P.size is 0 exponent becomes random numbers since its unsigned
   cout << "The size of P is now: " << P.size() << endl;
   //I use a for loop to insert the contents of P into the ostream later on
   ...
   return sout;
}
```

Now the test_Polynom.cc

```
int main()
{
vector<int> Poly1;
Poly1.push_back(1);
Poly1.push_back(2);
Poly1.push_back(3);
Poly1.push_back(4);
...
cout << Poly1.size() << " The size of Poly1" << endl; //Just making sure Poly1 was created with the right size
...
Polynom a1(Poly1); //creating the class object
...
a2.insert(cout);
...
return 0;
}
```

Now the output of my program is

```
4 The size of Poly1
A polynomial was created with the desired coefficients
1 2 3 4 Those were the content of P
The size of P is now: 0
```

So I'm stuck on why the contents of P are not carried over to my insert function. As far as I'm aware I'm not overshadowing the vector and creating a new one inside the function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You constructor is creating a local variable called P which has precedence of the class member with the same name.  You are building the vector locally and then throwing it away.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it right away